# List comprehension on the same list?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm new to Python and get an issue with list comprehension when applying it on the same list.

The code is

```
# both grid and dp are already defined as the following types:
# grid: List[List[int]]
# dp: List[int]
for j in range(0, len(grid)):
 dp = [v + dp[i] if i==0 else v + min(dp[i-1],dp[i]) for i,v in enumerate(grid[j])]
```

I thought this is equivalent to

```
for j in range(0, len(g)):
 for i,v in enumerate(g[j]):
  dp[i] = v + dp[i] if i==0 else v + min(dp[i-1],dp[i])
```

But the results are different.
Sample input:

```
dp = [0,5,5]
grid = [[1,3,1]]
```

List comprehension result: `dp = [1,3,6]`

`for` loop result: `dp = [1,4,5]` (expected)

Any suggestions?

Comment: In the loop example you are altering `dp` as you loop over it so the expression: `min(dp[i-1],dp[i])` is different.

Comment: @MarkMeyer so basically in list comprehension it's using the original values although some of them are already modified, similar to the a,b = b,a? Now I see how the result is computed in the list comprehension case. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be accumulating values across the various `j` iterations?  In the first you create a new `dp` each `j` iteration.  In the second you keep modifying `dp`.  Get things working for a single value of `j` before trying the outer layer of iteration.